# Clarification of Definition for Functional version of TSP

Tags: complexity-theory

The decision version of $TSP$ is $NPComplete$. I was reading about the functional version of $TSP$ i.e. the class $FP^{SAT}$.

It is mentioned in the original paper that TSP is complete for the class $FP^{SAT}[n^{O(1)}]$. By definition of the class, it means TSP can be solved in polynomial time by making $[..]$ calls to an $NP$ Oracle.

But I am still confused what $n$ is in case of a TSP instance?

Comment: Generally speaking, $n$ is the input size in bits, though in graph problems $n$ is usually the number of vertices. Assuming this is the unweighted version, it's not important whether $n$ is the number of vertices or the size of the input, since these are polynomially related.

Comment: Thank you. This is the paper. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000088900396

The Instance is : "Graph with integer weights on the edges".

I assume its an undirected graph as they do not talk about directed edges. So, do I take the 'input size' as the number of bits required to represent the incident matrix (with each entry 0 or the weight of the edge) of the problem ?

Comment: Right, $n$ is the input size, unless they are doing something in a non-standard way.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, what I thought is that $n$ is number of vertices. Only then binary search for TSP requires linear amount of calls.

Comment: @rus9384 The upper bound holds even in the presence of weights – the increase in input size is in your favor.

Comment: @J.Doe On page 11 it is clearly stated that $n$ is the input length.

Answer (score 3):

In definitions of complexity classes, $n$ is always the input length in bits.

Often the definitions are invariant under polynomial blowup (for example, polytime and logspace), and in such cases you can also take $n$ to be other parameters of the input, the resulting class being the same. For example, if the input is an unweighted graph, you can take $n$ to be the number of vertices.

Comment: I am still trying to grasp the concepts in terms of functional versions as they are very confusing. The paper says Clique is complete for $FP^{SAT}[log(n)}]$. Thus, for Vertex Count (V) - 1024, Input Size (n) = Log(VertexCount^2)) = 20. And the clique could be solved in $FP^{SAT}[log(n)}]$, so the maximum number of calls we are allowed to the NP Oracle are 5. I am not sure how we can solve clique using that many calls in polynomial time? And it gets worse as n doubles.

Comment: No – the input size is the length of the input *in bits*. In this case $O(\log n)$ denotes the same class of functions whether $n$ is the input length or whether $n$ is the number of vertices. Note that $\log n$ in this context probably means $O(\log n)$ – usually big O's are hidden in definitions of complexity classes.

Comment: Ok. But, then I can solve the weighted TSP using $O(log n)$ calls to NP Oracle, not $O(n)$!